# обрезать изображение ровным квадратом

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно полученное в форму изображение сделать квадратным

1. узнать высоту и ширину изображения
2. сравнить высоту и ширину в px
3. из большей величины вычесть меньшую получить результат
4. полученный результат поделить на 2
5. та величина которая была большей высота или ширина вычесть края сверху - снизу или слева - справа полученного результата делённого на 2

- ПРИМЕР:
  Пример:

Изображение имеет размеры 1200px (ширина) х 900px (высота)
Большая сторона - 1200px, меньшая сторона - 900px

1200px - 900px = 300px
300px / 2 = 150px

Так как ширина больше высоты, мы обрезаем с левой и правой стороны по 150px

Итоговый размер изображения будет квадратным со стороной 900px x 900px, обрезав лишние 150px с каждой стороны.

```
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
      $(galereyForm).on('submit',(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var galereyForma = new FormData($(galereyForm)[0]);
      $.ajax({
          type:'POST', 
          url: $(this).attr('action'), 
          data:galereyForma,
          cache:false, 
          contentType: false, 
          processData: false,
          success:function(data){ 
              console.log("Завершилось успешно"); 
              console.log(data); 
          },
          error: function(data){ 
              console.log("Завершилось с ошибкой"); 
              console.log(data); 
          }
      });
     }));  
    });
```

Comment: Нафига? Используй css и всё.

Comment: @Qwertiy не согласен. Если нужно сократить объем данных загружаемый с сервера, это может быть перспективно.

Comment: @AndreiFedorov, но в таком случае надо картинку на сервере обрезать и пересжать, а не на клиенте. А то кто-нибудь огромную bmp загрузит. Или обойдёт эту обрезку и загрузит не квадратную.